# Finding string in array and using next

Tags: arrays, ruby

This specific exercise is a codewats Kata, which asks the user to search through an array, and if a String is found, to skip to the next item in the array. The array should then be printed without any of the strings included. `[1, 2, "a", "b"]` is the array being searching through. I expect `[1, 2]`.

I tried:

```
def filter_list(l)
  print l
  i = 0
  while i < l.length
    l.each do|item| next if item.class == String
    return item
    i += 1
  end
end
```

I also tried this code without the while loop:

```
def filter_list(l)
  print l
  l.each do |item| next if item.class == String
    return item
  end
  print l
end
```

Both methods return the same result:

```
1
```

My code only returns the first element in the array.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Once again: you want to filter out all the strings from the array?

Comment: Yes exactly. And return the array with only the integers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to remove every String from an array you can use #reject.

```
array = [1,2,"a","b"]
=> [1, 2, "a", "b"]
array.reject { |element| element.is_a? String }
=> [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[1, 2, "a", "b"].grep(Integer) # => [1, 2]
[1, 2, "a", "b"].grep_v(String) # => [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
arr = [1, 2, 2, "a", "b"]
(arr.map(&:to_s) - arr).map(&:to_i)
#⇒ [ 1, 2, 2 ]
```

---

```
 zeroes = arr.count(0)
 arr.map(&:to_i) - [0] + [0] * zeroes
```